# Google Fitness API doesn't ask for consent

Tags: rest, google-api, google-oauth

I've been trying to get my Google Fitness API up and running. Getting the standard information works, but when I want to get information from the Fitness API, it won't register. It looks like it doesn't want to ask for permission.

I want Google to ask the user for permission by the following API's
[image: Google Consent Screen]

After I get an access token from Google, Postman has the following to say to me when I go to https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources:

```
{  "error": {
"code": 403,
"message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
"errors": [
  {
    "message": "Insufficient Permission",
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientPermissions"
  }
],
"status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"}}
```

Headers are fine because I've added the content type and authorization token. I don't know if it has something to do with my setup in Google API's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Together with a friend of mine, I've came to the solution.

I didn't know that the library I used for my react app, needed to know the scopes beforehand. So what I did was add the Scope tag to my login button and it worked.

```
<GoogleLogin
 clientId={CLIENT_ID}
 buttonText='Inloggen'
 onSuccess={this.login}
 onFailure={this.handleLoginFailure}
 cookiePolicy={'none'}
 scope={'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read'}
 />
```